# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011: how to retrieve dashboard owners?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

It is possible to retrieve (somehow) dashboard owners from Advanced Find (UI) or database or maybe through API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By code using API:

```
QueryExpression q = new QueryExpression(UserForm.EntityLogicalName);
        FilterExpression f = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
        ConditionExpression c = new ConditionExpression("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, dashboardName);
        f.AddCondition(c);
        q.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("ownerid");
        q.Criteria = f;

        EntityCollection ec = service.RetrieveMultiple(q);
```

It's not possible using Advanced Find.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to query the database instead, you can do so by querying the view called "Userform". The name of the dasboard is in the name column.

Best Regards

Stig

Comment: exactly in order to find out the table name I asked this question :) And I found it in the first sentence [UserForm.EntityLogicalName] of @Rodrigo's answer. But thanx :)